# Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows) -- how to limit when it has to count every single id within in this result

Tags: apex, trigger

We have about 3 million addresses and they each belong to a particular fiberhood, some fiberhoods have more than 200k addresses and there is no way to limit it down. I even looked into creating a new master detail relationship with all the other objects affected, but that is going be a nightmare. Was wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

this is the code called by the trigger

```
global with sharing class chkpoint_FiberhoodHelper {

global static void updateServiceAddressCounts(set<Id> fiberhoodIDs){
    Map<Id, Fiberhood__c> fiberhoods = new Map<Id, Fiberhood__c>();

    for(Id fiberhoodID: fiberhoodIDs) {
        if(fiberhoodId != null){
            fiberhoods.put(fiberhoodID, new Fiberhood__c(Id=fiberhoodID, Total_Addresses__c=0, Commercial_Requests__c=0, Commercial_Request_MRC__c=0.0, Custom_MRC__c=0.0, Sign_Up_MRC__c=0.0, Interest_MRC__c=0.0, Registered_Interest__c=0.0, Registered_Sign_Up__c=0.0, Un_Registered_Sign_Up__c=0.0, Registered_Custom__c=0.0));
        }
    }
    // savetest
    for(AggregateResult result: [select count(Id) cnt, sum(Commercial_Request__c) cr, sum(Commercial_Request_MRC__c) cr_mrc, sum(Registered_Interest__c) interests, sum(Registered_Custom__c) customs, sum(Registered_Sign_Up__c) signups, sum(Un_Registered_Sign_Up__c) unregistered, sum(Custom_MRC__c) custom_mrc, sum(Sign_Up_MRC__c) su_mrc, sum(Interest_MRC__c) interest_mrc, Fiberhood__c Id from Service_Address__c where Fiberhood__c in :fiberhoodIDs and Fiberhood__c != null group by Fiberhood__c]){         
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Total_Addresses__c = (Decimal)result.get('cnt');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Registered_Interest__c = (Decimal)result.get('interests');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Registered_Sign_Up__c = (Decimal)result.get('signups');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Registered_Custom__c = (Decimal)result.get('customs');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Un_Registered_Sign_Up__c = (Decimal)result.get('unregistered');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Custom_MRC__c = (Decimal)result.get('custom_mrc');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Sign_Up_MRC__c = (Decimal)result.get('su_mrc');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Interest_MRC__c = (Decimal)result.get('interest_mrc');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Commercial_Requests__c = (Decimal)result.get('cr');
       fiberhoods.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Commercial_Request_MRC__c = (Decimal)result.get('cr_mrc');
    }
    // Handle Mail Non Deliverable
    for(AggregateResult result2: [select count(Id) cnt, Fiberhood__c Id from Service_Address__c where M_Non_Deliverable__c = true and  Fiberhood__c in :fiberhoodIDs and Fiberhood__c != null group by Fiberhood__c]){
        fiberhoods.get((Id)result2.get('Id')).Mail_Non__c = (Decimal)result2.get('cnt');
    }
    update fiberhoods.values();


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system should "optimize away" this part: `and Fiberhood__c != null`, but you definitely don't need it in your query. It does nothing good for you. Clone the original set, then remove null, ensuring that there is never a null value:

```
Set<Id> fiberhoodIdsDup = new Set<Id>(fiberhoodIds);
fiberhoodIdsDup.remove(null);
```

If you can't get this any more optimized, then you'll need to move this to asynchronous code. Call a Queueable, and you'll have relaxed query limits. Aggregating a lot of data in a trigger context is often non-trivial.

Comment: okay, good advice I will give that a try